# What Java version comes with Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, java

I have created a Java Swing application using JDK 1.6. Many customers are asking if my application can run on Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6, so I wanted to add this question to my website's FAQs section, and I wanted an accurate answer. I am trying to answer this:

1. What Java version comes with Mac OS X 10.6 ?
2. What Java version comes with Mac OS X 10.5 ?
3. I know Mac OSX 10.5 comes with a Java version less than 1.6, so is there a simple way to update it to 1.6 so my program can run fine on it?

Comment: You should ask this on http://Apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @Jonas ... I do not agree with you. This question many developers ask concerning the Java environment, and many will try to find its answer in StackOverflow.com as it concerns the development process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.6.7 has:

```
jonatan:~ $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)
```

for 10.5 here is the update

```
http://support.apple.com/downloads/Java_for_Mac_OS_X_10_5_Update_4
```

> This release updates Java SE 6 to
>   version 1.6.0_13, J2SE 5.0 to version
>   1.5.0_19, and J2SE 1.4.2 to 1.4.2_21.

The update process is easy - the user should run: "Software Update..." from the "Apple" menu.

Comment: Note that [1.6 is only available for 64-bit machines](http://blogs.oracle.com/cmar/entry/java_1_6_finally_available).

Comment: The 64-bit restriction for Java 1.6 is only true for MacOS 10.5 (Leopard). If you use MacOS 10.6 (Snow Leopard) you get Java 1.6 for 32- and 64-bit from Apple.